# Fine-Uploader not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fine-uploader

I am trying to use Fine-Uploader in a asp.net mvc core project, but nothing is being displayed, besides a box, In the inspector in google chrome , I am getting qq is not defined.

I am adding the js,css in _Layout.cshtml

CSS

```
   <environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/azure.fine-uploader/fine-uploader- gallery.min.css" />
    <link rel="import" href="~/lib/azure.fine-uploader/templates/gallery.html"  />

</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet"        href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/azure.fine-uploader/fine-uploader-gallery.min.css" />
    <link rel="import" href="~/lib/azure.fine-uploader/templates/gallery.html" />

</environment>
```

JS

```
     <environment names="Development">
     <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/azure.fine-uploader/azure.fine-uploader.min.js">    </script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/azure.fine-uploader/azure.fine-uploader.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

I have the gallery added in a cshtml as per the example on the fine-uploader site, if I remove the first script tag I get the fine-uploader box showing(See image below), but nothing else is shown.

```
 <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
    <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
        <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
        <div>Upload a file</div>
    </div>
    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
        <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
    </span>
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
        <li>
            <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
            <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                Retry
            </button>

            <div class="qq-file-info">
                <div class="qq-file-name">
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-btn qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                </div>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>
</div>
```

```
<title>Fine Uploader Gallery UI</title>


<div id="uploader"></div>

<script>

    var uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploader({

        element: getElementById("uploader")



    })
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you read my answer again. The screenshot you posted confirms my suspicions.

Comment: @Ray I am not sure, why it is not loading correctly. It is added the same way as the other scripts.

Comment: The problem is likely server side

Comment: @Ray Thanks for the help, I fixed it, I was missing a '@section Scripts {}' surrounding the script tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a @section Scripts surrounding my script tag

```
<title>Fine Uploader Gallery UI</title>


<div id="uploader"></div>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/azure.fine-uploader/dist/azure.fine-uploader.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
    <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
        <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
        <div>Upload a file</div>
    </div>
    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
        <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
    </span>
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
        <li>
            <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
            <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                Retry
            </button>

            <div class="qq-file-info">
                <div class="qq-file-name">
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-btn qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                </div>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>

    <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
        <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </dialog>
</div>
</script>
            <script>
            var uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploader({
            debug: true,
            element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
            template: 'qq-template'
        })
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> qq is not defined.

This indicates that you are not loading the fine uploader js file correctly onto your page. I suggest looking at your network requests. You will likely see that either the js file isn't loading at all, or the contents are incorrect.